# how to call parameterized and non parameterized constructor from single object in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading

If object is instance of whole class, why didn't we can call parameterized and non parameterized constructor from single object.

```
class ovrldng {
public:
    int var;
    ovrldng() {
        var=101;
        cout << "Default constructor assigned value into var=" << var ;
    }

    ovrldng(int x) {
        var=x;
        cout << "Parametrized assign 'x' value to var =" << var ;
    }
};
```

**from main** how to call both constructors from **one** object;

Comment: An object can only be constructed once.

Comment: Before C++11 you couldn't use constructor delegation

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the calling constructor (with parameter) in constructor (without parameter), also known as constructor delegation:

```
ovrldng() : ovrldng(101)
{
    cout << "Default constructor assigned value into var=" << var ;
}

ovrldng(int x) : var(x)
{
    cout << "Parametrized assign 'x' value to var =" << var ;
}
```

and in main you can call both constructor just creating one object:

```
int main()
{
    ovrldng obj;
}
```

Hope that this what you are searching for.

Comment: "calling constructor in constructor" that's called constructor delegation

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to initialize an object through multiple constructors.

Which one to use it is up to personal preferences/coding guidelines, use case (maybe the constructors are to different to share code) and technical limitations (e.g. the compiler doesn't support C++11 features):

```
#include <iostream>

//Your current solution (works pre C++11)
class ovrldng_1 {
public:
    int var;
    ovrldng_1() {
        var = 101;
        std::cout << "ovrldng_1 var =" << var << std::endl;
    }

    ovrldng_1(int x) {
        var = x;
        std::cout << "ovrldng_1 var =" << var << std::endl;
    }
};


//Using a function to initialize (works pre C++11)
class ovrldng_2 {
public:
    int var;
    ovrldng_2() {
        init(101);
    }

    ovrldng_2(int x) {
        init(x);
    }

    void init(int x){
        var = x;
        std::cout << "ovrldng_2 var =" << var << std::endl;
    }
};


//Using a default value (works pre C++11)
class ovrldng_3 {
public:
    int var;
    ovrldng_3(int x=101) {
        var = x;
        std::cout << "ovrldng_3 var =" << var << std::endl;
    }
};


//Calling one constructor from another (constructor delegation) (C++11 is required)
class ovrldng_4 {
public:
    int var;
    ovrldng_4(int x) {
        var = x;
        std::cout << "ovrldng_4 var =" << var << std::endl;
    }

    ovrldng_4() : ovrldng_4(101){}
};
```

To test these you can just create an object of every type (and with every defined ctor) and check the output:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ovrldng_1 a;
    ovrldng_1 b(212);
    ovrldng_2 c;
    ovrldng_2 d(212);
    ovrldng_3 e;
    ovrldng_3 f(212);
    ovrldng_4 g;
    ovrldng_4 h(212);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ovrldng_1 var = 101
ovrldng_1 var = 212
ovrldng_2 var = 101
ovrldng_2 var = 212
ovrldng_3 var = 101
ovrldng_3 var = 212
ovrldng_4 var = 101
ovrldng_4 var = 212
```

**Addendum** 
You should use initializer lists (see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists).
I only didn't use them to make the different classes easier to compare.

Comment: Sir, I wanna know how to call parameterized and non parameterized constructor from single object. and Why??
If object possess all the things class have..!!

Comment: Short answer: Not possible. Why don't you update your question and explain why you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks sir..I just wanna know the memory structure pointed by object.
It is not related with any Project or something..I have just started learning cpp ..it is the result of curiosity

Comment: The memory structure is defined by the class declaration not by the initialization. So the structure isn't different regardless of which ctor you call. The values may depending on the implementation.

Comment: @SimonKraemer `init` could be private for better encapsulation. @rs_prog isn't my answer good, it is simple and that way you are calling both constructors?

Comment: @sop Yes and `var` should be private as well.